# How to stop binding.pry from executing inside a loop?

Tags: ruby, pry

Consider the following code:

```
require 'pry'
(1..5).each {                                                                                       
  binding.pry                                                                                     
  puts 'test'                                                                                       
}
```

After getting into first `pry`'s session I want to continue running the script as if `binding.pry` is not there. Even when I edit the file not leaving the session, commenting the line out, and type `exit` or `continue`, it's invoked nevertheless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `!!!` or `exit-program (exit-p)`, but it will raise an exception.

Comment: Also you can disable-pry and 'enable-pry' again 
https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#disable_pry

Comment: Awesome, but I didn't see any exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Another Solution is `disable-pry`

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the file without leaving the session, then the old, unedited code that has binding.pry on each iteration of the loop is still loaded. Upon editing a file, it does not get reloaded. You would have to exit the pry session in order for pry not to pop up again.

What is it exactly you're trying to do? I may be able to help you more if I could see the code you're trying to debug.

Comment: When I run `exit` or `continue`, doesn't they quit the pry session? To make it clear. I run the script, it stop at `binding.pry`, I edit it with `edit` command (comment out the line), `exit`, and it stops at `binding.pry` again. You might be meaning that ruby is still running the script, so editing it doesn't make any difference. And the only option I see is to stop it at the beginning, and set a breakpoint, which might be a hassle. I just started using `pry`, so I might well be wrong here.

Comment: As for what exactly I was doing, I don't think it matters. But I debugged tests today. I wanted it to stop. But `pry` didn't let me stop it with `Ctrl-C`. Either it handled it itself, or popped up too fast for me to react. And some other script. It's all about loops, really. When you try to make it stop, but it just won't.